# Macbook 9,1 Ubuntu 14.04 keyboard issues on resume

Tags: keyboard, suspend, power-management

I have read many similar post and tried nearly all post to no avail.  Screen and keyboard illuminates; but no keys actually work.  (I tried the F6 trick too) Trackpad does allow me to move the pointer, but as it is locked nothing is clickable.  Additional notice if I add a usb keyboard/mouse and external display; resume goes to black screen on both displays and neither keyboard, trackpad, or mouse work. On cold reboot all is fine.  I do not see anything interesting in the /var/log/pm-suspend.log.
root@Not-MacBook:~# tail /var/log/pm-suspend.log
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Tue Jan  6 13:43:17 CST 2015: Finished.

root@Not-MacBook:/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d# dmidecode -s system-product-name
MacBookPro9,1
root@Not-MacBook:/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d# uname -a
Linux Not-MacBook 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux